# 'No such index at level 1' error on for loop to add columns

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices. Each matrix has either 11 or 12 columns, so I'm trying to standardize all of the matrices to have 12 columns.

```
# Normalize all pages to have 12 columns; some currently have 11 others 12
# 'out' is a list with each element being a matrix
for (i in out) {

  # check if each matrix has less than 12 columns
  if(ncol(out[[i]])<12) {

    # if it does, then insert a column of blanks between columns 1 and 2
    out1 = out[[i]]
    out2 <- cbind(out1[,1],"",out1[,2:11])
    out[[i]] <- out2
  }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following message:

> Error in out[[i]] : no such index at level 1

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `for (i in seq_along(out))`? (In your code, `i` is the first element if `out`, so `out[[ out[[1]] ]]` likely makes no sense.)

Comment: `lapply(out,function(x) if(ncol(x)==11){cbind(x,matrix(NA,ncol=1))} else{x})`

Comment: Tried using seq_along but didn't work.

I see what you're saying with ```out[[ out[[1]] ]]``` but am otherwise unsure how to replace the first element of the list with the new version of the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generalized way to do this using `lapply` -

```
# first a reproducible example
matlist <- list(
  a = matrix(1:6, ncol = 3),
  b = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
)

matlist
$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

$b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Now, similar to the problem, all matrices should have 3 columns where missing column(s) are inserted between column 1 and 2 -

```
# get max column number from list
maxcol <- max(sapply(matlist, ncol)) # directly use 12 here if preferred

# update original list
matlist[] <- lapply(matlist, function(x) {
  coldiff <- maxcol - ncol(x)
  if(coldiff > 0) {
    cbind(x[, 1], matrix(NA, nrow(x), coldiff), x[, 2:ncol(x)])
  } else {
    x
  }
})

matlist    
$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

$b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   NA    3
[2,]    2   NA    4
```